# Save image after it gets loaded without the right click menu

Tags: image, browser

I was just watching some street view images in [this website](http://mattdesl.github.io/google-panorama-equirectangular/demo/) where if you refresh everytime it loads up a new image. Then I realized a image was too beautiful and I was trying to save that image somehow, and it is when I came to know that I can't right click and same street view (Panorama) images. I thought maybe going to developer tools then network might help but it requires to be opened before I load up the page or I have to refresh the page which is disasters in this case.

I know the images loads up on browsers gets saved in the data folder of the browser. But I don't know how to retrieve them or is there any other ways I can save the image?

Comment: This question is more likely to find a good answer on superuser.com, it's not a code question.

Comment: Thanks, I was also bit confused if I should ask the question here or is there other sites I should post this.